# How can I filter a grep-like search to require 3 strings to be in a given order and distance?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file from which I want to see if 3 specific strings exist within a limited range of lines.

The first 2 will always be right after one another and the 3rd will be X number of lines after #2. #3 can also exist more than once, but I only want the first one.

E.g.

```
nope    
nope
foo    
bar    
nope
nope
nope
nope
baz
nope
baz (ignore this one)
```

If foo and bar exist right after one another and baz within say 100 rows, I "win". How can I achieve this easily?

Right now I have it broken down into many small steps, creating temp files with grep -A100 (and other grep stuff) whenever I find "foo" and then checking them for "bar" and "baz". It works, but it's not pretty.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I assume that the blank lines were a formatting artifact and unintentional. If not, please make that specific -- it directly impacts the logic if it needs to filter on whether the line *directly* before a `bar` is `foo`, or if the last *non-empty* line before a `bar` is `foo`.

Comment: BTW, showing the ugly tempfile solution you're using now would make this a better question, just by way of making it clear what your current thinking about the problem is, and maybe answering questions like the above before they need to be asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `grep` here at all: `awk` is the right tool for the job.

```
awk -v range=100 '
BEGIN { matchedFoo = seenFoo = seenBar = (0 - range) }
/foo/ { seenFoo=NR }
/bar/ { if (seenFoo == NR-1) { seenBar=NR; matchedFoo=seenFoo; } }
/baz/ && (seenBar > (NR - range)) {
  print("Matched foo@" matchedFoo ", bar@" seenBar ", baz@" NR);
  exit(0);
}
'
```

...emits, with your sample input:

```
Matched foo@3, bar@4, baz@9
```

...correctly emitting the line numbers for the desired instances. (Of course, you could store the full strings in addition to the numbers if you wanted).

---

A quick word on the logic:

- The reason we have separate `seenFoo` and `matchedFoo` variables is so that a new `foo` without a following `bar` doesn't change the line numbers shown in output.
- The reason we initialize everything to `0 - range` is so the values are still valid integers (so no math fails), but also so a `baz` within the first `range` lines of input doesn't see a value of `0` as meaning there was a match for `bar` on line 0, and thus within our 100-line search distance.